# How to show Grid Line on MFC dialog? (not in design but while running dialog)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I am devloping custom dilaog editor in MFC.

I want to show grid lines on MFC dilaog when I run the dilaog(on DoModal)

how this can be achived in MFC? is there any property to be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The grid is only used at design time and simply doesn't exist at run time.

You can draw some horizontal and vertical lines yourself though...